# How to convert dt_date yyyy-mm-dd to dt_date yyyy/MM/dd in ssis?

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, etl

I have my DOB column like this  `yyyy-mm-dd` (not string) how can I convert into  `yyyy/mm/dd` using ssis?

Comment: Date columns have no format. Formats apply only when dates are formatted as strings for display, or when strings get parsed to produce a date. If you want dates to appear a certain way in a report or application, specify the format in the application itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, how can I achieve that ?

Comment: What is the source?  A SQL query?  You can use FORMAT (depending on SQL version) or use a convert or cast).  Or use a data transformation if inside a data flow task.

Comment: Thanks , Just realize that I can just use date(dt_date) instead of db_date.

Answer (score 1):

Just realize that I can just use date(dt_date) instead of db_date.